# Restricting specific file extensions getting uploaded (server side)

Tags: java, filter

I am working on below scenario since last two days,
I have developed a java filter that check whether request is multipart type,
      If it is, I want to restrict .php file getting uploaded.
In servlet filter I successfully retrieved type of file, if it's valid one, i have forwarded that request to proceed.
Now my business logic that was working exactly fine without filter is now failed to upload.
My project is using Spring framework.
At business logic, I'm using MultipartRequest(class of spring) as casting in.
Invoking request.getFileNames() which is returning nothing after involving filter.

In filter, I have wrapped request after validating file extensions as follows:
All form fields are set in parameter map that will be passed with request.
And File type field is set as attribute in request object.

Would you guys please help?

Thanks,
Namrata Shah

Comment: Just provide the code which you have written in the filter for blocking .php files. Also provide the error stack trace if you are receiving any

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not the simplest solution would be to remove the filter and do the validation in your upload functionality, say uploadFile() method for example. You can check whether the file type is php and throw an error.

Comment: I am restricted to make any change in source of web application. If I'll make any change in upload file logic, I am having other 40-50 places in around 70 web applications. so filter is the only solution that I'll place to intercept any request coming to a tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

In `doFilter()`,

I have checked whether received request is instance of HttpServletRequest. If yes, then it'll be parsed if it's a multipart req using below code:

```
parseRequest():

{

List<FileItem> multipartItems = null;
        try
        {   multipartItems = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        }
        catch (FileUploadException e)
        {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        for (FileItem multipartItem : multipartItems)
        {
            if (multipartItem.isFormField())
            processFormField(multipartItem, parameterMap);
            else
            processFileField(multipartItem, request);
        }
            return wrapRequest(request, parameterMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for `processFormField()`:

```
 String name = formField.getFieldName(),value = formField.getString();
 String[] values = parameterMap.get(name);

 if (values == null)
 {
     parameterMap.put(name, new String[]{value});
 }
 else
 {
     int length = values.length;
     String[] newValues = new String[length + 1];
     System.arraycopy(values, 0, newValues, 0, length);
     newValues[length] = value;
     parameterMap.put(name, newValues);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for `processFileField()`:

```
request.setAttribute(fileField.getFieldName(), fileField);
```

then, I wrap request as follows:

```
private static HttpServletRequest wrapRequest(
            HttpServletRequest request, final Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)
    {

        return new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request)
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
            {
                return parameterMap;
            }

            public String[] getParameterValues(String name)
            {
                return parameterMap.get(name);
            }

            public String getParameter(String name)
            {
                String[] params = getParameterValues(name);
                return params != null && params.length > 0 ? params[0] : null;
            }

            public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames()
            {
                return Collections.enumeration(parameterMap.keySet());
            }
        };
    }
```